# condtional input fields in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to develop a form that has three input field of which third input with name `schoolname` should only be visible if age below 15 otherwise it should be hidden. when user enters age below 15 third field should pop up and should be required field. I developed form but when I enter age above 15 the form is not submitting as i set school field as hidden. what should i do to get form submitted if age is above 15 and a mendatory school name field i fage below 15

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var age = $("#submit").val();
  if (age < 15) {
    $("#schoolname").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
  <input id="age" type="number" name="age" placeholder="age" required />
  <input id="schoolname" type="text" name="schoolname" placeholder="Enter your school name" style="display:none" required />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You forgot to close `if` statement and note that there is no such `<submit>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup` event

```
$("#age").keyup(function() {
  var age = $("#age").val();
  if (age < 15 && age > 0) {
    $("#schoolname").show();
  } else {
    $("#schoolname").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: if age is greater than 15 form is not redirected to action page which I forget to add in form tag like action="test.php"; I think since it is required school name field and it is hidden thats why it is not working..

Comment: How do you want to your form will working? You can or do not redirect if age over 15 or remove property `required` in `schoolname` input.

Comment: If i remove required from schoolname input, and age is less than 15 , how can i make sure user will enter school name and will not leave the schoolname field empty

Comment: You can also add event: `
    $("#submit").on("click",function() {
      var school = $("#school").val();
       if (school != "") {
          return true;
       } else { return false;}
    });`  This will block form submit if `school` is not entered

Answer (score 0):

```
var age = $("#submit").val();
```

change to

```
var age = $("#age").val();
```

`#age` mean that you are getting element by `id`, and that `id` is age which you needed in the form

Answer (score 0):

Your `age` has wrong input value which is string that's why it will be fail. You need change

`var age = $("#submit").val();`

to

`var age = parseInt($("#age").val());`

`parseInt()` will convert the string to integer which faster and better way for `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#age").on("change",function() {
  var age = $("#age").val();
  if (age < 15) {
 $('<input id="schoolname" type="text" name="schoolname" placeholder="Enter your school name" required />').insertBefore("#submit");
  }else{
  $("#schoolname").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
  <input id="age" type="number" name="age" placeholder="age" required />

  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: if age is greater than 15 form is not redirected to action page which I forget to add in form tag like action="test.php";

Comment: Probably because of the required hidden input,Try the code above